# Can I get per task profiling stats in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to investigate straggling tasks in my PySpark job (tasks which take much longer than the p50/p75 tasks) to understand why some tasks take much longer to execute versus other tasks in the same stage.

The default PySpark profiler provides aggregate stats for RDDs, but is there a way I can get profiling stats at the task level?